# How to restrict or permit people from using your Content provider

Tags: android, mobile, android-contentprovider

If I create a ContentProvider and want it to be available to certain 3rd party apps but not too others.

How would one go about that?

Answer (score 0):

Use permissions. Read about them here:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-creating.html#Permissions

Then you just need to publish those permissions to only those parties you wish to allow access.

Answer (score 0):

You can add permission to provider. like

```
<provider
            android:name="com.example.app.provider.MyProvider"
            android:authorities="com.example.myprovider"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:readPermission="com.example.permission.READ_PROVIDER" />
```

and write your own permission into manifest

```
<permission
        android:name="com.example.permission.READ_PROVIDER"
        android:description="provider_desc"
        android:label="@string/permission_access_label"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

Write this permission to manifest of the application which want to access provider.

Where signature insures that applications (which access provider and original are signed with same certificate)

---

Read more about [Writing your own Content Provider](https://www.grokkingandroid.com/android-tutorial-writing-your-own-content-provider/)